# Any way to check if a bool** pointer to pointer contains a true value in C without loops?

Tags: ios, c, pointers, optimization

I am trying to optimise an iOS app and just wanted some advice on an issue I am having.

I have a `bool**` which can hold up to 1024 * 1024 elements. Each element defaults to `false` but they can also be changed to `true` at random.

I wanted to know if there is a streamlined way to check if a `true` value is contained by any of the elements, as, in a worst case scenario over a million iterations would be needed to do this check using two loops.

I could be completely wrong but I had thought about casting the memory to an int, in the belief that, as a `false` value is equal to 0, if all the elements are false then the result of casting it to an int would, I had thought, be 0. This is not the case however.

What I may have to go with is to keep a tally of the number of true values as they are toggled but this could turn quite messy very quickly.

I hope I have made myself clear enough without code but, if you need to see any code, just ask.

--Edit--
So I decided to go with mvp's answer. Then when I need to check if a certain bit is set:

```
uint32_t mask32_t[] = {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08,
    0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80,
    0x100, 0x200, 0x400, 0x800,
    0x1000, 0x2000, 0x4000, 0x8000,
    0x10000, 0x20000, 0x40000, 0x80000,
    0x100000, 0x200000, 0x400000, 0x800000,
    0x1000000, 0x2000000, 0x4000000, 0x8000000,
    0x10000000, 0x20000000, 0x40000000, 0x80000000
};

bool bitIsSet(uint32_t word, int n) {
    return ( word & mask32_t[ n ] ) != 0x00;
}

bool isSetAtPoint( uint32_t** arr, int x, int y ) {
    return bitIsSet( arr[ (int)floor(x / 32.0) ] [ y ], x % 32 );
}
```

Comment: Do you need to know if any one element is true, and nothing else? Do you need to know which element is true?

Comment: My first thought was a count of how many are true.

Comment: By chance, isn't this [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) simulator? If yes, there is much better way to solve this riddle

Comment: @Monkey - Just need to know if any, as in not none, are true. Which element(s) bears no significance.

Comment: @mvp - Nope, not that but interesting read nonetheless :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably best optimization you can make is to convert your 1024x1024 array of booleans into array of bits. This approach has some benefits and drawbacks:

1. `+` Bit array will consume 8 times less memory: 1024*1024/8 = 128KB.
2. `+` You can quickly test many bits at once by checking 32-bit integers quickly. In other words, finding first non-zero bit can be 32-times as fast.
3. `-` You need to create custom routines to read and write bits in this array. However, this is rather simple task - just a bit of bit twiddling :).

Comment: This method looks promising, however the number of elements will not always be in multiples of 8, i.e. it could be 520 * 700 for instance. Would this cause a problem you can think of? I know that those 32bit integers would need to (eventually) be dropped down to individual bits but apart from this, any foreseeable issues you can think of?

Comment: @TomHaz Just round upwards to nearest possible size, and ignore the unneeded extra bits.

Comment: Just like @user694733 says, align to 32-bit boundary to keep it easier to count, compare and copy bits - memory loss will be negligible. If your bit array is very sparse, it might be more efficient to keep it compressed either as a whole, or compressing smaller sub-parts independently for better granularity. It will complicate access methods, but might make it possible to keep your whole structure in just few KB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the answer is no. You need to write a loop to check.

You cannot cast a composite value to an `int`. You don't report a compiler error, so I suspect you actually tried casting the pointer to your array to `int`, which is legal; however, the result will only be 0 if the pointer is `NULL` (that is, not pointing to anything.)

You can streamline the checking code by using a bitvector instead of an array of bools. (You'd also save quite a bit of memory.) However, that involves a lot more code, and it's fairly messy. If you were using C++, you would have access to `std::bitset`, which is a lot easier than writing your own, but has the disadvantage of needing a compile-time size.

Answer (score 0):

Using integer array has been said here already and is probably the best option, but here's a another approach.

If number of `true` nodes is very low compared to `false` nodes, you could turn the problem upside-down: Store coordinates of the `true`-nodes instead.

I'm thinking of a hashset or BST where you would use position of the `true` node as a key. Then checking the existence of `true` would be trivial: check if your data structure has any coordinates stored in it.